# sales_flat_order returning strange results from sql query

Tags: magento-1.9, database

If I do `Select * from sales_flat_order` I get over 23000 rows returned

If I do `Select * from sales_flat_order where customer_id ='1'` I get 74 rows returned

If I do `Select * from sales_flat_order where customer_id <>'1'` I get 5487 rows returned

Why doesn't the total of queries 2 and 3 match that of query 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the orders should contain customer_id as NULL

```
Select * from sales_flat_order WHERE customer_id IS NULL;

Select * from sales_flat_order WHERE customer_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Try above queries and cross check your total data.

Comment: Yes, they add up correctly. So I guess NULL customer_id entries are for guest checkouts right?

Comment: Yes Null customer_id entries are for guest users.